# Is it possible to connect to a host computer of Colab with some protocols like VNC or SSH?

Tags: google-colaboratory

A hosted runtime is like a complete-functional remote server in some sense but it doesn't have an IP address that can be accessed worldwide(or I haven't found it?) so traditional ways to connect does not apply. I wonder what else can be done.

Comment: You can do that with this Python module.
https://github.com/demotomohiro/remocolab This page explains how to access Google Colaboratory using ssh with remocolab:
https://internet-of-tomohiro.netlify.com/google_colab/ssh.en.html This page explains how to access Google Colaboratory using VNC with remocolab:
https://internet-of-tomohiro.netlify.com/google_colab/vnc.en.html